# Flow Not Returning Desired Results

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate, number

I have a recurring Flow that kicks off once a day to test a List to see if any of the 'Titles' have a 'DueDate' that equals 30 days, if yes send an email.

I have two variables:

Name: varNumberOfDays

Type: Interger

Value: 30

Name: varQualificationTitle

Type: String

Value: String('Driver')

I have an 'Apply to each' Condition:

items('Apply_to_each')?[DaysRemaining] is equal to  'varNumberOfDays'

The List column 'DaysRemaining' is a calculated column.

Without the Apply to each condition the flow returns 60, the exact number of "Driver" titles on the List; so, that filter works. There is only one "Driver" title with a DaysRemaining of 30 on the List, however when I use the Condition nothing is returned and no email is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured why fight; instead, I simply changed the List 'DueDate' from a calculated column to single-line text (that populates through a PowerApps patch. Now, I can filter on 'DueDate'.